# connect to linux vm using bastion through azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-bastion

How to connect to a linux VM which is created on azure portal with private IP (no public IP) using azure-pipeline.yaml

Comment: That sounds complex, how about just installing devops agent to that VM?

Comment: i cant use this as agent i have some tasks before this task like start that vm. looking for some sample code to use bastion to ssh into the VM.